# winforms gridview cell contents changed

Tags: c#, winforms, events, gridview

I have a gridview which gets populated via DataSet.xsd and table adapters.

Which event can I use to determine when the user double clicks a cell and modifies it's values?

You would think it is `DataGridView_CellValueChanged` but that event triggers every time a row is created/bound which is not what I want.

I want the event that gets triggered, when a user double-clicks a cell to put it in edit mode, and then changes it's value. So if the value does not change the event should not fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGridView Event CellBeginEdit fires when user starts editing. You can store value here and compare last and current value on other Event CellEndEdit.

Comment: Perfect. That did the job. Thanks